# Proof in Coq with named parameters in constructors

Tags: coq

I'm trying to prove `mapCCoption`. If you compare the definition of `BB` to `CC`, they are the same except in `CC` the named type parameters are in the constructor. This prevents me from completing the proof because when I destruct an object of type `CC option a` I lose any information about type `option`.

```
Inductive BB (m : Type -> Type) (a : Type) : Type :=
  | bb : m a -> BB m a.

Inductive CC : (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type :=
  | cc (m : Type -> Type) (a : Type) : m a -> CC m a.

Theorem mapBBoption (a : Type) (b : Type) (f : a -> b) (x : BB option a) : BB option b.
Proof.
apply bb.
destruct x as [o].
destruct o as [a0|].
- apply (Some (f a0)).
- apply None.
Qed.

Theorem mapCCoption (a : Type) (b : Type) (f : a -> b) (x : CC option a) : CC option b.
Proof.
apply cc.
destruct x as [m1 a1 o].
???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should use inversion instead of destruct:

```
Theorem mapCCoption (a : Type) (b : Type) (f : a -> b) (x : CC option a) : CC option b.
Proof.
apply cc.
inversion x as [m1 a1 o].
inversion o as [a0|].
- apply (Some (f a0)).
- apply None.
Qed.
```